# Making bootstrap prints look similar to screen design

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Anyone know if there exists any print stylesheets that is optimized for printing the pages similar to what is actually shown on screen? I know it's impossible to get it exactly the same, but even slightly similar look (tables similar style etc) would help.

The default print stylesheet completely ruins the look.

Answer (score 0):

**it's not impossible**

1. Clone container/div to get HTML to print
2. add CSS to head
3. Create a new window
4. insert cloned data into the new window
5. on document ready trigger print command

```js
function print() {

    var containerToPrint = '';

    containerToPrint = $(".container-needs-to-print").clone();
    /* can be body */

    // insert you CSS in head in new window
    var totalHtml = '<head><link rel="stylesheet" href="' + urlPath + 'css/style.css"></head>' +
        '<body>' + containerToPrint.html() + '</body>';

    // create a new window
    var newWindow = window.open('', 'PRINT', 'height=' + $(window).height() + ',width=' + $(window).width() + '');

    // add content to new window
    newWindow.document.write(totalHtml);
    newWindow.focus();

    $(document).ready(function () {
        setTimeout(function () {
            newWindow.print();
            newWindow.close();
        }, 2000);
    });
}
```